# How do I detect the value of my variable in this function?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, if-statement, progress-bar

```
function addTenPercent() {
    // locate the progress bar and store it in a variable
    var bar = document.getElementById("progressBar");
    // add 10 to the value
    bar.value += 10;
    if (bar.value > 10) {
        alert("test");
    }
};
```

Ok i have this function and I want to detect when the progress bar is beyond a certain point using the if statement, what I am doing does not seem to work, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's in `bar`? I mean, what type of element is there?

Comment: It is a JavaScript progress bar.

Comment: It depends on what type of element `bar` is

Comment: I beg to differ, there is a `<progress>` tag available, maybe that's what the OP is using.

Comment: actually it is, progressbar's `.value` property is number not string, so more info is needed

Comment: Where's OP, this is all speculation. What kind of element is `bar`?

Comment: @PatrickEvans - That's right, forgot about that, the progress tags value is a float between 0.0 and 1.0.

Comment: No, it's an [actual value](http://jsfiddle.net/LX2Xh/). @PatrickEvans - good point, didn't know that. ) Still would be great to see the real HTML structure underneath this question - in the question itself.

Comment: its ok i didn't know either till adeneo said something about progress tags so had to test it in the console :P

Comment: Ok here is it with the html structure. http://pastebin.com/5sPEbsWq

Comment: Works [fine](http://jsfiddle.net/W9VPQ/) here (at the first step `alert` isn't shown, as value is 10 - which isn't greater than 10, obviously). Note that I've removed the `bar.value` line present in your pastebin - it fails (as `bar` is `undefined` when the line is evaled) with an error. Check your console, do you see any error there when you run the script?

Comment: @user3749296 you also have syntax error in your code, trailing `}` right before the `</script>` tag

Comment: I get a error telling me "addTenPercent is not defined" when trying to  run that function via the button.

Comment: is the function defined inside another function?

Comment: No it is not defined inside another function.